# Get internal tags in Ghost

Tags: ghost

Is there any way to get all internal tags in Ghost using the api and the `get` helper?

In my `post.hbs` template I can do this and it works:

```
{{#post}}
  {{#foreach tags visibility="internal"}}
    {{name}}
  {{/foreach}}
{{/post}}
```

But in my `page.hbs` I tried this and it only shows tags with public visibility.

```
{{#get "tags" limit="all"}}
  {{#foreach tags}}
    {{name}}
  {{/foreach}}
{{/get}}
```

I also tried

```
{{#get "tags" filter="visibility:internal"}}
```

and

```
{{#get "tags" visibility="internal"}}
```

but it does not return any tags.

Is this not implemented and if so why not? This would be super useful for my use case.

I did read the docs and https://themes.ghost.org/docs/get#section--fields- says that valid fields for tags are `id, uuid, name, slug, description, image, created_at, created_by, updated_at, updated_by`. Visibility is notably missing, does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify the `visibility` attribute when you access the tags, not when you retrieve them, in this case, it's in the `foreach`:

```
{{#get "tags" limit="all"}}
    {{#foreach tags visibility="internal"}}
        {{name}}
    {{/foreach}}
{{/get}}
```

This will loop over the internal tags only. Apparently you have to get all the tags and then filter this way, I didn't find a way to get only the internal tags from the begining.